An Error Occured: Error: Reached maximum depth for account resolution
I am currently working on a CRUD DApp (from the Solana bootcamp official video). While calling the update_journal_entry instruction from UI, I am getting the following error:
An Error Occured: Error: Reached maximum depth for account resolution
Creation and Deletion instructions are working perfectly fine.
Anchor Code is mentioned below for reference
#![allow(clippy::result_large_err)]

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("9CqUpGEwpB53mMneGb1QZNFa7NspydzhsCDbWY1g4Q8Q");

#[program]
pub mod crudapp {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_journal_entry(
        ctx: Context<CreateEntry>,
        title: String,
        message: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let journal_entry = &mut ctx.accounts.journal_entry;
        journal_entry.title = title;
        journal_entry.message = message;
        journal_entry.owner = *ctx.accounts.owner.key;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn update_journal_entry(
        ctx: Context<UpdateEntry>,
        _title: String,
        message: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let journal_entry = &mut ctx.accounts.journal_entry;
        journal_entry.message = message;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn delete_journal_entry(_ctx: Context<DeleteJournal>, _title: String) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(title: String)]
pub struct DeleteJournal<'info> {
    #[account(
    mut,
    seeds=[title.as_bytes(), owner.key().as_ref()],
    bump,
    close = owner
  )]
    pub journal_entry: Account<'info, JournalEntryState>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(title: String)]
pub struct UpdateEntry<'info> {
    #[account(
      mut,
      seeds = [title.as_bytes(), owner.key().as_ref()],
      bump,
      realloc = 8 + JournalEntryState::INIT_SPACE,
      realloc::payer = owner,
      realloc::zero = true
    )]
    pub journal_entry: Account<'info, JournalEntryState>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(title: String)]
pub struct CreateEntry<'info> {
    #[account(
      init,
      seeds=[title.as_bytes(), owner.key().as_ref()],
      bump,
      space = 8 + JournalEntryState::INIT_SPACE,
      payer = owner
    )]
    pub journal_entry: Account<'info, JournalEntryState>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct JournalEntryState {
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    #[max_len(50)]
    pub title: String,
    #[max_len(1000)]
    pub message: String,
}


This is a client anchor problem. Make sure you update to the newest anchor version.
If that does not help you can use accountsPartial or accountsStrict instead of just accounts and put in all the needed accounts manually.
Make sure you are putting in all the correct accounts in the frontend. The auto resolution should work. If you post your frontend code we can maybe see if there is a problem. Does it also break if you directly use the code from the bootcamp repository?
